# Phoenix Server Won't Start -- Postgrex Fails (EXIT) no process

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When attempting to start via `mix phoenix.server` the following error is reported until the server is killed:

```
    ** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(Postgrex.TypeServer, {:fetch, {'localhost', 5432, "database_name", :copy, [{Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime, []}, {Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, [library: nil]}]}}, 60000)
```

The database and permissions have all been verified working.

The full stacktrace:

```
    Last message: nil
    State: Postgrex.Protocol
    [error] GenServer #PID<0.820.0> terminating
    ** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(Postgrex.TypeServer, {:fetch, {'localhost', 5432, "database_name", :copy, [{Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime, []}, {Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, [library: nil]}]}}, 60000)
        ** (EXIT) no process
        (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:596: GenServer.call/3
        lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:486: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap/3
        lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:353: Postgrex.Protocol.handshake/2
        lib/db_connection/connection.ex:134: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
        lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your app's mix.exs file lists `:postgrex` as a dependency.

For example:

```
    def application do
      [mod: {Chat, []},
      applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :postgrex]]
    end
```

Comment: When there is no process, the solution would be to start a process. This has nothing to do with `postgres` and basically has no added value at all. I downvoted the question, I would not downvote the answer since it is technically correct, but I see no reason to keep this question at all.

Comment: the question states a searchable, replicable symptom. There is no issue with 'no process' phoenix runs, postgres is running, there is a specific error printed to the console & the answer provides a resolution to that issue.